# How to register push notification receiver in the background in NativeScript-Vue

Tags: android, vue.js, nativescript, pusher, nativescript-vue

I'm working on a NativeScript-Vue mobile app and I want to register a push notifications receiver in the background so that when the server sends push notifications I can show them to the user even when the app is not running in the foreground. What is the best way to accomplish that on both Android and iOS?
Any recommendations or help would be much appreciated

I tried using "nativescript-background-fetch" library but couldn't figure out the requirements to make it work.
I'm using "nativescript-pusher" library to start a broadcast receiver in the foreground.

I expect to register a broadcast receiver in the background, and whenever the server sends a broadcast, the app should receive the message and act accordingly (show a notification in my case)

Comment: The whole architecture of Push Notification is different for iOS & Android, you will not be able to achieve it without writing platform specific code. On iOS a notification is triggered by the system upon receiving, but on Android you may decide whether or not to show a notification and style it further. Moreover `nativescript-background-fetch` is POST / PULL not PUSH. Since you are using [Pusher](https://pusher.com/docs/channels/channels_libraries/libraries), you must refer their client libraries and docs.

Comment: I've used Firebase Cloud Messaging through [nativescript-plugin-firebase](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-plugin-firebase/blob/master/docs/MESSAGING.md) and so far everything has always worked. Apparently you can also use a [different push service](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-plugin-firebase/blob/master/docs/NON_FIREBASE_MESSAGING.md), but I haven't tried it yet.